# Weird interface implementation

Tags: java, interface

Sorry I had the wrong code before...

So I have an interface that looks like:

```
public interface Player { 
    void setPartner(Player partner); 
}
```

And I have an implementation of that interface that looks something like this:

```
public class Human implements Player
{
    private Human partner;

    public void setPartner(Human partner)
    {
        this.partner = partner;
    }
}
```

So the compiler says that I am not implementing every method from Player which indicates to me that I have to match the parameter type of the setPartner method exactly, even though the a Human, is a Player. Is there any good way of getting around this or implementing this differently?

Comment: I don't get an error with your code.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? IIRC, newer versions will support what you are trying to do here by detecting that a `Human` is indeed a `Player`. However, older versions will not have this feature.

Comment: Method covariance starts with Java 5.

Comment: @Code-Guru - Nice insight. Covariant return types were introduced in Java 1.5 (a.k.a. Java 5).

Comment: Ah, now that you edited it, the code does generate an error. See the answer by @Frank .

Comment: @FrankPavageau Method covariance only applys to return types, not parameters, correct? (This is to clarify the comments because of the edited OP.)

Comment: @Code-Guru Return types and declared exceptions can be covariant, right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have covariant parameters (what happens if you manipulate your Human instance through the Player interface?), however you can use generics.

```
public interface Player<T extends Player<T>> {
    void setPartner(T partner);
}

public class Human implements Player<Human> {
    private Human partner;

    public void setPartner(Human partner) {
        this.partner = partner;
    }
}
```

---

However, you can't force the implementing class to actually use its own type as the type parameter of Player.

Comment: Why would manipulating a `Human` through the `Player` interface be cause for concern?

Comment: @meriton In the OP's code? human.setPartner(robot) where human is a Player variable referencing a Human instance, and robot another Player variable referencing a Robot instance, which also implements Player, is legal since Player.setPartner() takes any Player. However, Human.setPartner() would only take another Human.

Comment: So the one problem that I see with this is that there is no way to force the class that is implementing Player to use it's own class as the type for T. Is there perhaps a way to get around this?

Comment: @user1721559 No, you can't force it.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, method parameter is invariant. That means `void setPartner(Player partner)` method signature is different than `void setPartner(Human partner)` method signature even though `Human` is-a `Player`. So you cannot implement (or override) like that.

Care must be taken while extending a class becuase if `Player` was a class and the method was not abstract than it would actually work but you would have overloaded the method instead of overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense as `setPartner(Human)` is more restrictive than `setPartner(Player)`. By implementing `Player`, you're saying that `setParner` accepts any `Player`. Your `setPartner(Human)` method only accepts the subclass `Human` and not other `Player` implementations.